# How to add TabBarController in pre-designed Xib using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xib, uitabbar

I have already designed my two Xibs using interface builder.
[image][image]

I am using autolayout and all constraints are set. Now I want to add tab bar to switch between these two screens. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/ios-tab-bar-controller-example.html...Hope it helps...you might have to adjust constraints as with tabbar view height changes...

Comment: A swift guidline will be appriciated thanks